# Why Do i keep getting an error when I try to delete a single record from a database? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am having trouble deleting a record from a databse. I keep getting this error.

```
PG::Error: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 1: ...ctive_items" WHERE "users_items"."" = $1 ^ : DELETE FROM "users_items" WHERE "users_items"."" = $1
```

**Here is the method.**

```
def delete_items
    @destroyer = UsersItems.find_by_item_id(params[:items_id])
    @destroyer.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Item deleted"
    redirect_to itemsearch_path
```

end

```
<a><%= link_to "Delete Item",{:controller => "items", :action => "delete_items",:method => :delete,:item_id => item.id}%></a>
```

Comment: Why u calling UsersItems.find_by_item_id(params[:items_id]) with itemS_id instead of using item_id?

Comment: Can you put your UsersItems model?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<a><%= link_to "Delete Item",{:controller => "items", :action => "delete_items",:method => :delete,:item_id => item.id}%></a>
```

For this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Item",{:controller => "items", :action => "delete_items", :item_id => item.id}, :method => :delete%>
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning it should be `items_id` not `item_id`.

Comment: Yeah, that was type on my behalf, but it didn't help. I am still getting that error.